# yarn link doesn't run prepublish script, so what else can I do to develop an ember addon locally?

Tags: typescript, ember.js, yarnpkg

I have an addon that is linked to my app (for local dev) using `yarn link`

This creates a symlink in node modules to the addon directory.

However, I am using ember-cli-typescript, which has a prepublish script that builds my .ts files into .js, so when I am developing locally, prepublish doesn't get run, my .js do not get created, and the app crashes.

Maybe I could .gitignore all the .js and have them get built in ember-cli-build.js ?

Or should I be doing something besides `yarn link` for local dev?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this should work in ember-cli-typescript 2.x, but I'm stuck on 1.x for now. Possible workaround: https://github.com/typed-ember/ember-cli-typescript/issues/695